# Why is there currently no memory region in Java where no gc happens?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In many of our modern applications use cache to give a performance boost to the application. Now this cache might be in the sizes of some GBs.
But using this cache with current JVMs might cause huge performance issues due to GC cycles and all.

So my question is why does not java provides an easy way to use some space inside heap where GC will not happen.

There is some solution in form of off heap storage but it comes with its own downsides such as ser/der of objects.

Is there any particular reason for not providing this space.
Or i am asking something terribly wrong out here.

Comment: Why should a cache cause GC cycles if it's allocated and referenced?

Comment: Marking part takes a whole lot of time in largers sized JVMs

Comment: Generational garbage collectors usually don’t touch such memory anyway, unless insufficient RAM requires a major gc. If you have insufficient RAM, forbidding gc would imply just failing. In either case, the only fix would be adding more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about [sun.misc.Unsafe](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe).

This feature actually allows you to write Java code going into the direction that you are envisioning. Important enough to be coming as official part with [Java9](https://blog.hazelcast.com/using-sun-misc-unsafe-in-java-9/), after years in a grey area.

But to answer your direct question: how do you think that should work? You can't have the cake, and not have it at the same point.

When you leave a region of memory to be **managed** by the JVM, then the JVM **must** do garbage collection. If something in some memory area becomes legit for collection, it needs to go away.

In other words: if you want that the JVM doesn't touch a certain memory area - then the **burden** should be on you - because now your application must manage itself. The application has to "place" things into that area, and has to make sure they get discarded when that becomes necessary.